# Сделать и зациклить эффект

Tags: jquery

в документации нашел дрожание по клику

```
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( ".callmeicon" ).effect( "shake" );
});
```

как сделать чтобы элемент с определенной периодичностью двигался.не по клику

Answer (score 1):

```
  setInterval(function() {$( ".callmeicon" ).effect( "shake" );}, 1000);
```

1000 - это время для повтора в милисекундах.